# What happens after the penalty if a player is snookered behind a free ball?

Tags: rules, snooker

What happens after the penalty is applied when a player is snookered behind a free ball? This question pertains to the rule when a free ball has been nominated, but the player not only fails to sink the free ball, but also snookers the other player with it. In that case the rule says:

> Not potting the free ball incurs no penalty, so the striker may play a
>   snooker using the free ball, gratis. However, if said snooker is
>   achieved by having the free ball obstructing the ball on, then the
>   strike is a foul and a penalty of the value of the ball on is awarded
>   to the opponent.

Okay, but that still leaves the player snookered. For example, let's imagine Player A has a free ball and nominates the green ball. He snookers the cue ball behind the green. So, in that case Player A will have fouled and Player B receives 4 points. What happens then? Player B will still be snookered behind the green. Does B have to try to escape the snooker, even though he was awarded points for the foul?

Answer (score 1):

Player B gets a free ball, because he is snookered after a foul.